# Drawing Graphics obtained by GetDC doesn't work when inside a loop

Tags: c#, windows, drawing

I'm trying to draw graphics directly to screen, but when i use it inside `using` then it doesn't seem to work for some reason. I want to avoid creating several instances per millisecond to avoid additional cpu usage.

I have a IDisposable class ManagedDC which holds an IntPtr to DC and a graphics class which is gets initialzed by Graphics.FromHdc() on class initialization. When i put a loop with graphics code inside `using` block no errors happen but nothing seems to be drawing either. Doing `using` inside a loop works though, but it creates additional load.

Code of ManagedDC class:

```cs
        class ManagedDC : IDisposable
        {
            [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
            [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr dc);

            public ManagedDC()
            {
                pointer = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
                if (pointer == IntPtr.Zero) Throw();
                graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(pointer);
            }

            public IntPtr pointer { get; private set; }
            public Graphics graphics { get; private set; }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                graphics.Dispose();
                graphics = null;
                if (ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, pointer) == 0) Throw();
            }
            void Throw()
            {
                throw new Exception("win32 error code: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
            }
        }
```

Problematic code:

```cs
            using (ManagedDC dc = new ManagedDC())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    dc.graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 50, 50, 100, 100);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
```

I expected `for` inside `using` to be working as usual, but instead it doesn't draw anything to screen. `using` inside `for` works as intended but creates new instances every time for no reason.
I'm wondering why it happens, and if there's any way to fix it.

Comment: I can't reproduce it; works for me with `using` outside of the loop on Windows 10.

Comment: Freezing message loop for 2 seconds is indeed "Problematic code"... you should rethink your approach...

Comment: It's a console application, i did the Thread.Sleep() as an example. I'm running Windows 7 if that changes anything.